# CSS @media - Stop stretching content after exceeding max-width

Tags: css, media-queries

Currently I have `@media only screen and (max-width: 1231px)`, but when my screen width exceeds 1231px, everything looks messed up.

Instead, after the screen width exceeds 1231px, I want to keep the body centered horizontally, and append whitespace on the left and right of the body. How do I do that?

Comment: Have you tried setting a max-width:1231px and a margin: 0 auto to the body? This will grow the body till 1231px and then center the body in the window if it grows any further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a `div` container and put all your content inside:

```
.container {
  max-width: 1231px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```